# Regular language and Finite Automata (FA).

Tags: automata, regular-language

Consider the following FA
[image: an finite automata]

1. Build a transition graph with only two states that accepts the same language as the FA.
2. Build a FA which accepts the same language as the FA, but has fewer states.

So far I have the following as my answers:
1.
[image: Finite auto with only two states]

2. I don't know how to do 2. but I watched [this YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/0XaGAkY09Wc). I'm not sure how to apply that logic here.

Is my first answer correct and what is the answer to the second one?
Thank you.

Comment: Your first answer is incorrect; in the second term, it should be $(a+b)^*$. Also can you see what would be a short English description of the accepted language? It has to do with the letter $b$.

Comment: I’d have analyzed it as $a^*b(aa^*b)^*b(a+b)^*$; this might make it a little easier to see what Aravind is suggesting.

Comment: I see my mistake. Let's call the states starting, middle, top and final states for discussion sake. I see that the top state have an edge that comes back to the middle state with input b so I need to concatenate the top state with the final state instead of making it OR (+). I get it. Thanks you guys. What about question 2? At least give me a clue.